# DNS Domain Issue

Tags: dns

we are maintaining our DNS account to GoDaddy DNS Provider for our servers, Right now we have an problem, If someone has to register domain or sub-domain from any of other DNS provider or GoDaddy DNS provider it allow's to activated and those domains are pointing directly to our servers easily, how to avoid these kind of cases, how to restrict some other peoples have to register some illegal domains like (porn or some other sites) with our server ip.

How to avoid this kind of problem.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about Unix-like operating systems to the extent laid out in the [Help Center](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Questions regarding the DNS system and would probably be more appropriate for [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com).

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking how to prevent somebody from setting up the DNS servers for their domain to return your server's IP address, you can't.  When you own a domain, you can configure the DNS to return any IP you want, no matter who controls that IP address.

You can, however, use name-based virtual hosting to configure your HTTP server to respond differently when addressed with an unauthorized hostname.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply, How to write those kind of config in HTTP srever to overcome the above issue, can you give some hint for us.....

Comment: @user201078, that depends on what HTTP server you're using, which you didn't say.

Comment: We are using Apache HTTP Server....